# Log4j Rollingpolicy and MaxbackupIndex

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

Am using the following code to rollover logs each and every minute and it works perfectly.

```
log4j.appender.AllFlows=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.AllFlows.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.AllFlows.rollingPolicy.File=E:/Logs/AllFlows.log 
log4j.appender.AllFlows.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=E:/Logs/AllFlows.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}
log4j.appender.AllFlows.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.AllFlows.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AllFlows.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %x - %m%n
```

However i just want to know , are they any alternatives for MaxbackupIndex as this is not working as expected when i use TimebasedRollingPolicy?

Am using log41.2.17 and apache log4j extras

Comment: there is solution using custom log appender - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58729657/7179509

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using the standard API of log4j or even  with the Extras.

However, you can use the class [**`org.apache.log4j.DailyMaxRollingFileAppender`**](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender) <sup>**1**</sup>, e.g.:

```
log4j.appender.AllFlows=org.apache.log4j.DailyMaxRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.AllFlows.File=E:/Logs/AllFlows.log 
log4j.appender.AllFlows.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.AllFlows.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
log4j.appender.AllFlows.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.AllFlows.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %x - %m%n
```

---

*Notes*

1. See the code of this class in [*Custom DailyRollingFileAppender with MaxBackupIndex*](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender).

Comment: okay. can you please tell me which log4j jar version has DailyMaxRollingFileAppender? 1.2.17?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using DefaultRolloverStrategy oin log4j2

```
<RollingFile name="LogFile" fileName="/logs/application.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false"
                         filePattern="//logs/abc-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %m%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/> <!-- Above pattern will allow the files to be rolled over at midnight -->
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
</RollingFile>
```